# Вывести данные из определенной таблицы в зависимости от ID пользователя

Tags: php, mysql

Как вывести данные на страницу из разных таблиц для каждого пользователя.
Например если в сессии пользователь с ID=5 тогда выводить данные из таблицы user5. И так для разных пользователей.
Надо что бы все выводилось при загрузке страницы.

Comment: $table = 'user'.$id;
.. FROM $table ?

Comment: Если Вы разделили данные разных пользователей по разным таблицам - срочно переделывайте структуру, пока не стало мучительно больно. Всё должно быть в одной таблице, плюс поле, идентифицирующее, какому пользователю принадлежит запись.

Comment: Akina
Все сложнее, есть группы, которые курирует пользователь. Для этих групп отдельные таблицы со своими id и другими данными.
Вот мне и надо подгружать таблицу для каждого пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

Если я конечно все правильно понял, то как-то вот так...

```php
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
if ( is_numeric( $id) && intval( $id ) > 0 ) {
    //Формируем sql-запрос к таблице групп которые курирует наш пользователь
    //Конечно же нужно делать через PDO и bindParams, но мы упростим
    $query = 'SELECT groupname, tablename FROM groups WHERE curator_id='.$id;

    //Далее мы выполняем sql-запрос после которого все записи нам вернуться в переменную $groupsList как массив
    foreach( $groupsList as $group ) {
        //Идем по списку таблиц связанных с указанным пользователем и выбираем из них то, что нам нужно
        $tableName = $group['tablename'];
        //Исходим из того, что набор полей в этих таблицах одинаковый - поэтому и запрос для всех одинаковый, иначе в чем смысл всего этого огорода с разными таблицами?

        $query = 'SELECT id, field1, field2, field3 FROM '.$tableName;
        //Опять выполняем sql-запрос, получаем то что нужно и обрабатываем это все
    }
    
    $tableName = '';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.
С этой частью разобрался.
Есть еще вопрос, сможете помочь?
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1345244/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb

Comment: Только что на него ответил :)

Comment: Нужна Ваша помощь.