# Передать данные пользователя в сессии в другой файл

Tags: php, mysql

Есть страница с записью сессии. На ней пользователь заполняет форму и данные пишутся в БД.
К этой странице подключен фай обработчик.
Как можно передать в обработчик например ID текущего пользователя, что бы на страницу загружались данные из БД пользователя и записывались данные в БД пользователя. У каждого пользователя своя таблица.
Как реализовать чтение и запись я разобрался. Не могу передать в обработчик ID пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

`Способ 1 (небезопасный)`:

```php
//index.php
//Каким-то образом знаем ИД текущего пользователя и пишем его в переменную
$current_user_id = ...;
```

```html
<!-- Внутри html-формы выводим его в hidden-поле -->
<!-- После сабмита этой формы значение этого поля придет в script.php -->
<!-- Небезопасно тем, что пользователь может прямо в браузере подредактировать значение этого поля и отправить на сервер измененное значение-->
<form action="script.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="current_user_id" id="current_user_id" value="<?= $current_user_id; ?>"/>
...
...
</form>
```

Соответственно в `script.php`:

```php
$current_user_id = $_POST['current_user_id'];
```

Далее запрос в БД.

`Способ 2`:

```php
//index.php
//Каким-то образом знаем ИД текущего пользователя
$current_user_id = ...;
session_start();
// и пишем его в СЕССИЮ
$_SESSION['current_user_id'] = $current_user_id;
```

```html
<!-- В форме уже ничего не прячем -->
<form action="script.php" method="post">
...
...
</form>
```

`script.php`:

```php
session_start();
//Получаем значение из сессии
$current_user_id = $_SESSION['current_user_id'];
```

Далее запрос в БД.

Comment: Почему то ничего не получается.

Comment: Боюсь без анализа Вашего кода, я помочь не смогу. Так что, перефразируя всем известную фразу - код в студию! :)